# «Libérée, Délivrée» Comment comprendre cette phrase?

Tags: traduction

Dans le film d'animation Disney « La Reine des Neiges », il y a une chanson appelée « Libérée, Délivrée ».

Comment peut-on comprendre son titre? Il ne me semble y voir qu'une répétition du même sens, i.e. « Freed, Freed » ou « Free, Free »

Toute aide sera appréciée.

Comment: If you're asking for a translation into English you're on the wrong site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a translation into English.

Comment: @Laure Is any type of question asking for the meaning of a phrase forbidden tout court in this community?

Comment: @Laure What about this one?  http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23755/translation-of-you-are-difficult-to-please

Comment: Your are pointing to a question asking about how to say something in French, I understand your question as asking how to say something in English. if that's not the case maybe you could rephrase your question?

Comment: This question is intesresting, «Libérée, Délivrée» is the translation of "Let it go". Knowing how you would translate it back in english is not trivial (also really translation nerdy).

Comment: @Jylo I agree with you but French Language is a a site about the French Language, the place to ask the question is http://english.stackexchange.com/! Note that there is a nice "answer" but it is not an answer about OP's question but about the meaning of *délivrer* and *libérer*. That's why I suggested OP rephrased his question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Libérer***, ***délivrer*** (and *livrer* for that matter) all share the same Latin root ***liberare***.

They have more or less diverged during the centuries but both *libérer* and *délivrer* still share a lot of overlapping meanings.

In the *Reine des neiges* song, one of the reasons why they might have been chosen and in this order is to mark a progression as *délivrée* is slightly stronger than *libérée*, it adds some "sense of relief" that is not necessarily in *libérée*.

---

« **Libérer** », « **délivrer** » (ainsi d'ailleurs que « livrer ») partagent tous la même racine latine ***liberare***.

Ces verbes ont plus ou moins divergé au cours des siècles mais beaucoup des divers sens de « libérer » et « délivrer » sont similaires.

Dans la version française de la chanson de « La Reine des neiges », une raison qui explique peut-être le choix et l'ordre de ces adjectifs est qu'ils marquent une progression. « Délivrée » est plus fort que « libérée » car il ajoute une composante de soulagement qui n'est pas forcément présente avec « libérée ».

Comment: Many thanks jlliagre. It's precisely what I was looking for.  The dictionaries that I usually use weren't being helpful in this case. ;)