# Comment traduire (si possible) « He pleases me BY DOING something »

Tags: traduction, anglais, prépositions

En Anglais on peut écrire « He pleases me by washing the car », qui veut dire « La chose qui me plaît, c'est son nettoyage de la voiture. » Mais en français, je ne peux trouver aucun exemple de « Il me plaît *par* faire qqch » ou « Il me plaît *de* faire qqch » (où ce dernier veut dire « je trouve plaisir à le faire », plutôt que « je ressens de la satisfaction à l'idée que qqch est fait » ).

Cette construction grammaticale existe-elle en Français ?

Comment: In English we'd say: **I like it when he washes the car**. and not: He pleases me by doing something. which is very odd. It's grammatical but no one would say it. "Il me fait plaisir **en faisant X". He is trying to please me by washing the car. There, too, it's "en" and not "par". by is not always par.

Comment: @Lambie That is not right;  You can say "He pleases me by washing the car". Plenty of examples [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he%20pleases%20me%20by%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en). ex: So he pleases me by writing short, coherent, analytical assignments and then he's free to write what he likes to write about.

Comment: Gotta agree with LPH here. I'm actually a native English speaker and a semi-fluent Francophone. The context here is, I was helping a kid with her French homework and she asked... basically the question I just posted. I couldn't find any examples or explanations online, so I came to the font of all knowledge, StackExchange.

Comment: Question similaire: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23755/translation-of-you-are-difficult-to-please

Comment: @LPH Have you actually **looked at those hits** from Google books?? The entire first page has books from the 1800s and early 20th century and the last one is from a book from Québec! We just don't go around expressing the idea of Il me fait plaisir en lavant ou nettoyant la voiture by saying: He pleases me by [doing x]. It is grammatical of course. It is not usual in every day conversation. In any event, you missed the main point: by is en here, not par. He knows I like it when he washes the car.

Comment: @LPH ngrams is not about spoken language. It's about what's written in books. So using it as some sort of proof about everyday-type speech is a contextual, not to mention historical, error. And maybe the kid you were tutoring was a French speaker. I am hard pressed to believe a "kid", native English speaker, asked you this.

Comment: Raison des corrections dans le texte de la question, et une précision supplémentaire // 1/ exemple de < verbe > : pas correct ; exemple de < **nom** > : corrrect. 2/ se plaire de qqch : pas correct ; se plaire **de faire** qqch : correct 3/ être heureux à faire qqch : pas correct ; être heurux **de** faire qqch : correct 4/ De nos jours on dit moins « Il me plait de faire quelque chose » mais de toute façons ça ne peut pas traduire « He pleases me by doing sth ».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traduire "He pleases me by washing the car" par "la chose qui me plaît, c'est son nettoyage de la voiture" n'est pas correct. Ce sont deux phrases certes aux sens similaires, mais bien différentes, qui ne signifient pas la même chose. Sans prendre en compte l'usage commun, cette phrase française donnerait "the thing that pleases me, is his cleaning of the car" en traduction littérale anglaise. J'espère que cette traduction à revers aide à voir un peu la nuance.

---

Si tu veux trouver une traduction spécifiquement pour la partie "by doing (something)", la forme la plus commune sera "en faisant (quelquechose)".

La clé ici, c'est la [préposition "en"](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/en/29043), qui sert à former le [gérondif](https://bescherelle.ca/gerondif/) du verbe faire (préposition "en" + participe présent du verbe, lui-même formé par la forme radicale du verbe + terminaison "ant").
Le gérondif sert de complément circonstanciel, entre autres pour exprimer la cause ou la manière.

Comment: Oui, voilà, c'est exactement ce que j'avais dit. Le par ici, c'est "en"  en français.

Answer (score 2):

The basic way consists in using a plain conjunction to represent the relation of cause (laver) to effect (faire plaisir).

- Il me fait plaisir **parce qu**'il lave la voiture.

One might notice how the préposition "par" mentioned in the text of the query is a component in the morphology of this conjunction (par ce que).

The construction "*Ce qui me fait plaisir c'est qu'il…*"

This construction can be used for expressing implicitly a relation of cause and effect.

- **Ce qui me fait plaisir c'est qu**'il lave la voiture.

The preposition "*en*" can also be used to express causality by means of the "*gérondif*".

> ([Le Verbe : Le Gérondif - Emploi](https://fr.syvum.com/cgi/online/serve.cgi/grammaire/verbe/gerondif_emploi.html))  Le gérondif comme un adverbe, a une fonction de complément circonstanciel CC.
>
> On utilise le gérondif comme un CC qui exprime le temps, la cause, la condition, la manière et l'opposition.

(Plenty of examples [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22me%20fait%20plaisir%20en%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr))

- Il me fait plaisir **en lavant** la voiture.
- **En lavant** la voiture il me fait plaisir. (*alternative*)